# Indefinite article + superlative adjective

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles, ellipses, superlative-degree

[There can no more be a best possible world than there can be a largest number.](https://books.google.es/books?id=NDRuBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA202&dq=%22there%20can%20no%20more%20be%20a%22&hl=es&pg=PA202#v=onepage&q=%22there%20can%20no%20more%20be%20a%22&f=false)

What does "*a largest number*" mean here? What is the difference in that sentence between "the" and "a"?

Answer (score 1):

"A largest number" means a number *N* such that no other number is larger than *N*.  The speaker believes that such a thing is impossible, and compares this to the idea of a best possible world.

(I speak only of the meaning here, not of whether these assertions, or this mode of reasoning, is valid.)

Comment: Then, what is the difference in that sentence between "the" and "a"?

Comment: If you know *there is exactly one "largest number"*, then you could say "the largest number".  If you do not know that (or you do not want to clam that) then you say "a largest number".  This guy thinks there is no largest number, so he says "a largest number".

Comment: Surely there can be no more than one largest number in a given set of numbers, if there is any at all. One would have to sum over several sets in order to ask "Do any of these sets have a largest number?"  And even then, the correct term is a _maximum_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: (I speak only of the meaning here, not of whether these assertions, or this mode of reasoning, is valid.)

Comment: In a negative context, you can do it: _There is no largest integer_ is the same as _There is not a largest integer_ or _There is not any largest integer_. But only when it's being denied.